# Tags de componentes específicos em linguagens/frameworks devem ser mantidas?

Tags: debate, tags

É necessário que especifiquemos tanto as tags de uma pergunta? Por exemplo, no Java existe o [swing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swing_(Java)) para criar componentes gráficos e, notei que existem várias tags desses componentes:

[jtextfield](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jtextfield), [jtextarea](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jtextarea), [jcombobox](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jcombobox), [jtable](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jtable), [jlist](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jlist), [jlabel](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jlabel).

Acredito que somente as tags [java](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) e [swing](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swing) na pergunta já cobrem qualquer pergunta relacionada a esses componentes específicos.

O mesmo vale para outras linguagens, por exemplo, HTML: 
[html-select](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html-select), [html5-audio](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html5-audio), [html5-video](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html5-video), [html-option](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html-option), [html-table](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html-table), [html5-history](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html5-history).

Acredito que detalhes de implementação podem ser descritos no corpo da pergunta não?! É necessário tags tão específicas assim? Podemos matar essas tags?

---

> **[@Wallace](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/4995/wallace-maxters) says:** 
>    sim. Laravel por exemplo é bem diferente de "PHP". Porque o framework tem suas próprias aprendizagens...

Não é isso. Falei de componentes específicos de linguagens/frameworks =) por exemplo, suponha que exista um componente "label123" no laravel, ai tu cria uma tag "laravel-label123".

> **[@Wallace](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/4995/wallace-maxters) says again:** 
>   Tipo "laravel-collect"... aí não, é palhaçada

Comment: Claro que é, isso facilita a pesquisa, swing é a tag generica de todos esses componentes, mas existem duvidas que são especificas de cada um. Claro que deve ser criado conforme a necessidade e não sair criando das centenas de componentes que a API possui. Se não me engano, a maioria de swing fui eu quem criei, justamente com esse objetivo: facilitar a pesquisa.

Comment: Agrupar por pesquisa você diz? Porque não precisa de uma tag "jist" pra eu encontrar uma pergunta de "jlist".

Comment: No SOEn tem todas essas tags. E apesar de quase ninguém se interessar muito por perguntas dessa tag, eu achei bem mais fácil referenciar e encontrar perguntas dessa forma. A pesquisa do site é uma ....., pesquisar via tag simplifica as coisas.

Comment: Mas se acharem que deve tirar... Só criei algumas porque diante da péssima pesquisa do site, ao menos pareceu facilitar direcionar e encontrar algumas perguntas mais especificas de cada tag.

Comment: Acho boa a discussão e acho que devem ser mantidas, se estão sendo bem usadas ou não é outro problema. Eu acho que as *tags* devem, ajudar localizar o que está procurando e pode ser algo específico assim. Eu só gostaria que todas perguntas estivem bem classificadas. O que eu acho que dá pra discutir é se deveria ter um `jlabel`, um `label` e um `xlabel`. Aí acho até que não, mas deveria ter uma forma de expressar que a pergunta é sobre *label*. O que complica um pouco porque tem casos que pode ser muito específico. De uma maneira geral essas de HTML eu gosto assim. Não é ambígua, é geral, útil

Comment: Interessante. Se eu vejo uma pergunta com a tag `html`, eu até posso resolver abrir para ver se consigo ajudar. Mas se vejo algo como `html-video`, dependendo do dia eu nem abro (por exemplo se eu estiver só dando uma olhada rápida antes de sair). Se eu estiver a toa, acabo abrindo de curioso mesmo.